# Any way to view close history of a question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

This question on SO was closed a few minutes ago.  Now it isn't, but has 3 votes to close.  So I guess it was closed, and reopened, and is on it's way to being closed again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232338/how-big-is-the-importance-of-a-bachelor-of-science

Is there a way to see the actual close history for a question?  Any way to prevent the loop of close/reopen/close when there is some disagreement on whether or not a question should be closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that it's been edited, you can click the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2232338/revisions) to see this.

(This form of link - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postid>/revisions - is always valid, but you have to type it in manually if no one has edited the post in question. For example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/38865/revisions.)

Answer (score 2):

> Any way to prevent the loop of close/reopen/close when there is some disagreement on whether or not a question should be closed?

No one user can vote to close or to re-open a question more than once. So the termination condition for such a loop is built into the system.

You could also ask a moderator (flag -> Requires Moderator attention) to lock the question, thereby preventing it from being re-opened/closed. But this is rarely necessary.

Comment: Wish I could mark both answers correct since my question really had two parts.  Thanks for answering the other part!