# How to view history of question close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

How can I see the history of close voting on a question? I'd like to see when votes were made, when they aged away, etc.

- The question timeline at `/posts/<question-id>/timeline` does not show this information.
- The suggestions in [Any way to view close history of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38865/any-way-to-view-close-history-of-a-question) only work if the question has been closed. It doesn't show vote history.

I would like to see this information for question such as [Are there alternatives to cglib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261947/are-there-alternatives-to-cglib), which is patently off-topic but hasn't yet been closed. Due to the high view count, I wonder if the close votes are just ageing away each time someone tries to close it down. If I could see this in some kind of history, I'd consider flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: At the risk of being proven wrong, I'd guess that VTC + downvote is more effective than simply VTC on a highly voted question.

Comment: @devnull Perhaps. I tend not to DV unless the question is poor. For all I know, this was on-topic in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

There's no query in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that you could make to find this information.

I guess it's possible that you could visit that question at least once a day and keep track of how many current close votes it has, and compare that from the previous day. But other than that, or some like script to take a screen shot of that page each day, there isn't a simple way to just view this information.

Comment: The link to query in SEDE is broken